# wrapping elements (and arrays of elements) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Short form:

How would you implement something like the following in jQuery?

#### Details:

I have a pair of pure javascript functions that wrap HTML elements; it does what I need:

```
> wrap_element('li', 1)
'<li>1</li>'
> wrap_row('ul', 'li', [1, 2, 3])
'<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>'
```

But as a newcomer to jQuery, I'm certain there's a more elegant and idiomatic way to do something equivalent using jQuery.  Can you enlighten me?

---

For reference, here's my pure javascript implementation:

```
function wrap_element(tag, el) {
  return '<' + tag + '>' + el + '</' + tag + '>';
};
function wrap_row(row_tag, col_tag, cols) {
  var wrapped_cols = cols.map(function(col) {
    return wrap_element(col_tag, col)});
  var row = wrapped_cols.reduce(function(col, accum) {
    return col + accum; });
  return wrap_element(row_tag, row);
};
```

Comment: Is the goal to end up with HTML (as the above does), or an element tree?

Comment: Since I'm now using jQuery, ending up with an element tree would be appropriate.

Comment: FYI, using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in your code would be more readble. Also, you don't need that `reduce`. Just `join('')` the mapped array instead.

Comment: Use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on whether you want the contents treated as **text** or as **HTML**. Your current code treats the contents as HTML.

If you want the contents treated as HTML, you may as well build the structure as HTML and hit the parser once. In ES2015+:

```
function wrap_row(row_tag, col_tag, cols) {
    return $(
        `<${row_tag}>
            ${cols.map(html => `<${col_tag}>${html}</${col_tag}>`).join("")}
         </${row_tag}>`
    );
}
```

---

To do text instead:

To create a single element (wrapped in a jQuery object) with the given text, the jQuery way would be:

```
$("<td>").text("text");
```

You could wrap that in a function if you liked.

To do your `wrap_row`, something along these lines, probably:

```
function wrap_row(row_tag, col_tag, cols) {
    var row = $("<" + row_tag + ">"); // Or `var row = $(document.createElement(row_tag))`
    var col = $("<" + col_tag + ">"); // Or see above
    return row.append(cols.map(function(text) {
        return col.clone().text(text);
    }));
}
```

Or with ES2015+:

```
function wrap_row(row_tag, col_tag, cols) {
    const row = $("<" + row_tag + ">"); // Or `var row = $(document.createElement(row_tag))`
    const col = $("<" + col_tag + ">"); // Or see above
    return row.append(cols.map(text => col.clone().text(text));
}
```

It does, technically, create and throw away a DOM element it never uses. So perhaps (sticking with ES2015, easily translated to ES5 if you need):

```
function wrap_row(row_tag, col_tag, cols) {
    const row = $("<" + row_tag + ">"); // Or `var row = $(document.createElement(row_tag))`
    col_tag = "<" + col_tag + ">";
    return row.append(cols.map(text => $(col_tag).text(text));
}
```

That said, if this is a core thing you're going to use a **lot**, you might consider using the DOM:

```
function wrap_row(row_tag, col_tag, cols) {
    const row = $(document.createElement(row_tag));
    return row.append(cols.map(text => {
        const el = document.createElement(col_tag);
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        return el;
    });
}
```

Comment: `$(document.createElement(row_tag)` looks a bit like overkill. Without jquery one may as well use `document.createElement(row_tag)` I suppose (using `row.appendChild(...)` within the `.map`-lambda, which can also be a `.forEach` in that case).

Comment: @KooiInc - It saves jQuery sniffing the string to see whether it's a selector or HTML, then firing up the HTML parser to parse the HTML. For a utility function I'll go that extra step if my starting point is a tag name like that. Otherwise, I won't bother. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if JQuery is the right solution, but you can simply use the resulting string from a `wrap_row`-call to create a new element (fragment) and do something with that. In the snippet a row is appended to the existing table.

```js
const wrap_element = (tag, el) => `<${tag}>${el}</${tag}>`;
const wrap_row = (row_tag, col_tag, cols) => 
 `<${row_tag}>${cols
     .map( col => wrap_element(col_tag, col) ).join("")}</${row_tag}>`
;

const row = $(wrap_row('tr', 'td', [1,2,3]));

$('table').append(row);

console.log(`${row.html()} appended`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr><th>zero</th><th>one</th><th>two</th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, if the OP wants to treat the contents as HTML (as they are currently), that seems like the most straight-forward way in ES2015+.

Comment: Going with @T.J.Crowder's answer since it covers both HTML and DOM results, but I have to ask: is it now in vogue to use `const foo = (...) =>` rather than `function foo() ...`?

Comment: @fearless_fool - Opinions are quite divided on that topic; it's mostly a matter of style. There are four objective things to feed into your decision about style (and several subjective things): 1. Function declarations are hoisted, so you can use a function in code in the same scope as the function *before* the function declaration: `foo(); function foo() { }`. You can't do that with the `const foo = ...` version. But note that you *can* use `foo` in this situation: `const bar = () => { foo(); }; const foo = () => { };`. What matters is that you can't try to use `foo` [cont'd]

Comment: [continuing] before the `const foo =...` is processed in the step-by-step evaluation of the code (which means you can't do `foo(); const foo = () => { };` (but you **can** use it in nested scopes above the `const foo = `, such as functions defined above it; just not in the same scope, because it's too soon). 2. Arrow functions are lighter-weight than traditional functions. They don't have a `prototype` property with an object on it (traditional functions do in case they're used as constructors). 3. The binding (~variable) created for function declared with a function declaration [cont'd]

Comment: [continuing] can be assigned a new value: `function foo() { } foo = null;` Obviously, a `const` can't. 4. A traditional function can be called with `this` referring to a value you want it to refer to; arrow functions *close over* the `this` where they're defined, so you can't call them with a specific `this`. I won't list subjective arguments either way. So. Lots to consider, pros and cons on both sides. :-) In general, I'd suggest being consistent (either way) and then breaking that consistency when you have a specific reason to.

Comment: That's a great answer -- thank you!  I'm tempted to post "is it in vogue?" as its own question so you could respond to it properly, but the S.O. police would undoubtedly shoot it down as "too subjective".  :P